# Anyone used the MATLAB tool to produce C/C++ code? Is the resulting code viable for production use?

Tags: c++, matlab

We have some researchers who do a lot of work in MATLAB. We often would love to try their code as part of a bigger workflow that requies the algorithms to be put into C/C++ or Python. I've seen MathWorks advertise a tool to create native C or C++ code. How good is the code? Does it support the toolboxes? I'd still see it as an early prototyping tool but wondering how good the code is. Thoughts?

Comment: As any other automatic code generator - it is not very good, but I guess it can be a good starting point

Comment: Well, I worked at a company that made unmanned vehicles, and as I recall they used it to generate flight controls. However, I do not recall specifically if the code was used on vehicles at that point in time, or only in simulators. My hunch is that for sufficiently complex algorithms, especially those that are actively being developed, that it would be far more likely for a human to make a mistake than the code generator. As for questions of whether it is good for production use, I would say that the proper place to ask is at the company that makes the tool.

Comment: There are two different tools, first is available since last version (R2011a) and generates C/C++ from **MATLAB** code. Answers below indeed mention code generation from **Simulink**.

Comment: @VJo, There's no point in using a code generator if it's just the starting point, because you lose the connection with the original MATLAB/Simulink model.

Comment: @shelley The matlab code is also written by a human, therefore also error prone. **@Nzbuu** Right. I haven't thought about it

Comment: @VJo sure, but there are many reasons the human factor is minimized. 1. models are created in a way less prone to human error; e.g. MatLab. 2. when doing MatLab->code translation, you introduce many new chances for human error. 3. as with any commercial library code, the codegen is tested intensively by its users (likely many thousands of man-hours of testing), so the probability of a bug that causes incorrect code generation is reduced. codegen significantly lowers the chance of model->code errors in the first place, and these savings multiply for each iteration of a design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with mathworks extensively in the past on this.  The toolboxes are expensive, but the support is outstanding.  We benchmarked code generated for a specific DSP and it was within 10% the speed of hand generated code, and took a fraction of the time to generate.  Mathworks has been investing heavily in these toolchains the past several years and they are getting very good.  Some toolboxes are supported, look at the docs online.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'll have the MATLAB programmers check out the online docs to see if the Image Processing and Statistics toolboxes are supported. We can port to Python very quickly but don't get the best performance. It's adequate for some of our computer vision work, but some needs the raw petal to the metal power of C++. We're porting the code by hand currently and that is an expensive process!

Comment: Another possibility is to use a high-level C++ matrix library / toolkit such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) which has many Matlab-like [functions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

Answer (score 1):

The code produced by the Embedded Coder is, in my opinion, very good and it's a product that is widely used in industry, especially in automotive applications. It's generally designed to generate code from Simulink for real-time applications though. Look at the user stories on the website: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/embedded-coder/?s_cid=global_nav.

Support for toolboxes depends on what your requirements are. If you need something that only uses standard libraries, then support is limited, but if that doesn't matter to you, then you may have more success.

A word of warning though: it's expensive.

Comment: thanks for the comment. We currently have the MATLAB package, the Image Processor Toolbox, and the Statistic Toolbox. We do rapid prototyping and experimentation with different computer vision tech and then the code gets hand ported to C++. That hand coding is a very expensive process in manhours. I'm looking at three things: the quality of the output C++ code (is it production quality with performance similar to MATLAB native code), and will it support the two toolboxes, and what's the true TCO (total cost) compared to the manhours we are spending manually porting to C++ or Python.